# Trying to get javascript to remove text and reload it with AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have an HTML text area that reads in a text file and then lets a user edit the text. I have a 'refresh' button that uses AJAX to reload the file it is reading back into the text file. However my problem is, when I add something to the text area without pressing the save button and then press my refresh button, the text still stays in the text area.

What I expect to happen is that, the text I added gets deleted because the AJAX code replaces the text area with the file contents.

Below is my relevant code:

```
<script>
    function reloadFile() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("POST", "documents/test.txt", true);
        xhttp.send();
    }

</script>
<?php
    $myfile = fopen($file, 'a+');

    echo "<textarea id='demo'>";

    // go through each line in the file, print its contents.
    while(!feof($myfile)) {
        echo fgets($myfile);
    }
    echo "</textarea>";
?>
<button type='button'>Update Changes</button>
<button type='button' onclick='reloadFile()'>Refresh</button>
```

My question is, what can I do to so that when I press the refresh button, any text not actually saved on the actual file is discarded?
I tried placing

```
document.getElementById("demo").value = "";
```

at the beginning of the reloadFile function, but that didn't seem to do anything.

Documents/test.txt:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Header</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `type='refresh'` <-- what is "refresh" type?

Comment: @epascarello just noticed that.. sorry should be a button type. Problem still exists.

Comment: Does the function get called? Does the ajax call go out?

Comment: @epascarello yes to both. When I add the document.getElementById("demo").value = ""; , the text area clears and stays empty. I was expecting the content from the file to show up.

Comment: We need to see `documents/test.txt`.

Comment: Use `.value` for textareas instead of `.innerHTML`.

Comment: @PHPglue It is text though. I understand its HTML code but in a text area, its text if Im not mistaken. Nonetheless, using .value worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
```

to

```
document.getElementById("demo").value = xhttp.responseText;
```